# Bootstrap and AngularJS collapsed menu not going away after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code in my HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" ng-init="navCollapsed = true"
      ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    <a ui-sref="home" class="navbar-brand">GARS</a>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" ng-class="{'in': !navCollapsed}" id="navBarCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-if="mainCtrl.isLoggedIn">
      <li><a ui-sref="picks">Picks</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="matchup">Matchup</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="standing">Standings</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="allpicks">All Picks</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="leaderboard">Leaderboard</a></li>
  </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-if="!mainCtrl.isLoggedIn">
      <li><a ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
      <!-- <li><a ui-sref="register">Register</a></li> -->
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-if="mainCtrl.isLoggedIn">
      <li><a ui-sref="settings">Welcome {{mainCtrl.nickname}}!</a></li>
      <li><a href="users/logout" ng-click="mainCtrl.logoutUser()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

Everything works except when mobile device or when the collapsed (hamburger) button it clicked and you click on a link the menu stays there and renders page under it.   I have tried every jQuery thing I have found on SO and still have not had success.   Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need Angularjs directives to collapse navbar menu? Can't alone bootstrap do it?

Comment: Can you share your code via plunker or jsfiddler ?

Comment: @RandyR There is no need to add a angularjs logic for doing the collapse as Deepak told! because jquery is handling the collapse you are getting this issue!

Comment: The hamburger icon would not work at all unless I added the ng-click and other things.  The way things are above it works fine.  I can click on the button it displays dropdown menu.  Click on it again it goes away.  But still when clicking on a link such as "picks" or whatever the menu stays there and screen renders under it.   I'm working on a plunk with the same functionality.  To hard to convert everything I have to a plunk as the controller depends on so much stuff.  Also, if it makes a difference this is a SPA based site.